# Encode And Decode Base64 String Between Java And C#

Tags: java, c#, base64

I am stuck in a problem of conversion between base64 string, I hava a C# web API service, That Receives a Base64 encoded string. To That Service I am now consuming from Android(Java) So When I Encode a String to Base64 and send to C# Service It Recives Fine I have added A Breakpoint When I Decode It using online decoders It gives me the Correct Result, But My C# Web Api Service Can't Decode It Properly.

Here Is The Code Sinpet Please Help Me getting out of it Thank you.

Java Code: To Convert a String to Base64

```
 bytesEncoded = Base64.encode(string.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

C# Code To Decode:

```
  byte[] buffer = new byte[jsonString.Length];
  String str2 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
```

Recieved on C#:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us an example of your input and the output?

Comment: Your "decode" is actually another "encode" step. For "decode" it should `FromBase64String`. But: what is `jsonString` here? if that `string` is the base-64 text: just decode it.

Comment: And this is suspicious: `byte[] buffer = new byte[jsonString.Length];`

Comment: @Stefan fortunately `buffer` isn't actually used anywhere :)

Comment: It receives fine on C# i have debugged the code. I am posting String that recieved in C# Service Please Check the Update

Comment: @JawadZeb Please see what Marc Gravell posted, you don't want `ToBase64String` you want **From**Base64String when you decode it.

Comment: with the update: `jsonString` looks to hold base-64, so: just run `Convert.FromBase64String(jsonString)`

Comment: @MarcGravell yes Dear it's a string having base64String contents in it . this is the problem when i decode it does not gives me the result . just gives me another random text . The Code I have posted for C#, that one I'm using to decode it

Comment: @MarcGravell aaahhhhh Sorry Guys. Thank you Mark this was just a progrramming mistake . please add it as an answer so I can accept it. thanks alot

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks again you saved my Day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jsonString` appears to be base-64; in which case, you probably want:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(jsonString);
```

which *should* give you the same data you serialized into base-64 originally.

Note that it looks like your original data was a utf8 string, in which case:

```
var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Comment: It requires me to accept after 3 minutes . I'm waiting for it. You are Great. Thank you

Comment: Yes now I understood what to do. Thank You